# R: Unique object name in given environment

Tags: r, performance, loops, while-loop, vectorization

I have a function to return a vector of object names, that will be unique in a given environment:

```
find_unique_name <- function(nNames, environment) {

  un <- replicate(nNames, paste0(sample(LETTERS, 10), collapse=""))

  while (any(duplicated(un)) | any(un %in% ls(envir = environment))) {

    un <- replicate(nNames, paste0(sample(LETTERS, 10), collapse=""))
  }    

  return(un)
}
```

I would like to know if the speed of this function can be improved, as it is called many times in an algorithm. I would like to know if it can be vectorised, or at least if there is a way to do  it without the loop. I suspect this isn't the fastest way to find a vector of unique object names. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To generate new names, I would suggest using the following instead of the `replicate...`

```
gen_names <- function(nNames) {
  vapply(1:nNames, 
         function(i) {
           paste0(sample(LETTERS, 10), collapse = "")
          }, 
         FUN.VALUE = character(1))
}
```

You know that you want `characters` and you should use this information for optimization-reasons.

In every iteration, you list the names in the environment. This doesn't need to be done every iterations, because names in the environment don't change. And knowing how many names are valid new names, you don't need to create `nNames` at each iterations, just the difference you need.
Therefore I would suggest

```
get_unique_name <- function(nNames, environment = .GlobalEnv) {
  
  namesInEnvironment <- ls(envir = environment)
  
  un <- gen_names(nNames)
  un <- unique(un)
  un <- un[!(un %in% namesInEnvironment)]
  
  while(length(un)<nNames) {
    needNamesNr <- nNames - lenth(un)
    un <- c(un,gen_names(needNamesNr))
    un <- unique(un)
    un <- un[!(un %in% namesInEnvironment)]
  }    
  
  return(un[1:nNames])
}
```

I did some benchmarking and the following generation function for names is much faster:

```
gen_names2 <- function(nNames = 100) {
  apply(matrix(sample(LETTERS,nNames*10,replace = T),ncol = 10),
        1,
        paste0,collapse="")
}
```